# Name for Clerestory roof with windows at ridgeline?

Tags: roof, architecture

I know the term "clerestory" can be applied to a variety of rooflines which permit windows above the normal top of the interior walls, but was wondering if there's a specific name for the version where the roof comprises two "normal" sloped sections with a vertical offset at the ridgeline. This pic shows an example, albeit without the windows.

[image: WhatIsThisCalled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right: [Clerestory roof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerestory). [Here's one](http://www.build.com.au/clerestory-roof) with a centrally-located wall. Although most definitions do include reference to windows, it's the same roof structure.